# jQuery toggling dynamically generated nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

I'm currently designing a webpage presenting a twitter-like user input that generates an `<li>` (inside a `<ul>`) element in which are appended one `<h6>` element (the post's title) and a `<p>` element underneath (the content).This works, therefore the input and generation of elements is not the problem.

But what I want to do is use jQuery to *hide* the posts's content, and toggle it when I click on the post's title. The issue is that the event handler seems to work only for every second post. Whenever i post once more, the 1st post on the list can be toggled, the second not, third yes, etc.

From what I've seen in some answers, I've tried the `.click()` method, the `.on()` method, I've tried to replace `.toggle()` with`.hide()` and `.show()` under conditionals, then created a *class* with `display:none` to toggle on click. This was my last stop, and the result is described in the above paragraph. Here's the event handler:

```
$('.postinstance').on("click", "h6.postname", function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass('postOff');
});
```

The `.siblings()` is actually only the post content, but that's the only way I could get near what I wanted. When I replace `$(this).siblings()` with the actual class of the content element, every post's content toggles when I click on any title. 

How can I make each post open individually when I click on it?

[Here's a JSFiddle isolating the input & posts part.](https://jsfiddle.net/dobrevdelyo/38akaada/10/)

*I have looked thoroughly in Stack Overflow and other places, even tutorials, to solve this problem but although similar questions were found none of their answers provided a solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not attach event handlers to dynamically generated elements directly, instead use some common parent element. Here's a piece of your snippet where I changed the selector and everything started working:

```
$('.postlist').on("click", "h6.postname", function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass('postOff');
});
```

**Important note:** you must pull this piece of code out from $('.postbtn').click(..) one level up, otherwise for even number of posts toggling will not work!

Comment: Thank you, I changed the selector and moved the piece of code and it works like a charm!

So the problem occurred because the selector can't recognize a dynamically created element directly and was dependent on the event that's clicking on the `.postbtn`?

Comment: You're welcome :) Here's what was happening in your code during post button click: 1) create a post and prepend it in the list 2) create onclick handlers for **all** post headers (even the ones that existed before your new post). This resulted in some post headers having multiple click handlers which fired in sequence, hence toggling the corresponding post on and off and on and off... That's why you couldn't open exactly every even post! @user3722861

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was so desperate to understand :) Will keep all that in mind whenever I come across another dynamic generation (this is going to happen often I guess :D)

Answer (score 0):

And move this out of click handler:

```
$('.postlist').on("click", "h6.postname", function() {
      console.log(this);
      $(this).siblings().toggleClass('postOff');
});
```